# Bootstrap dropdown-menu with selects does not work on mobile

Tags: jquery, ios, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

We have a find a lawyer and find a law firm in our top header that drops down and works on desktop but does not work on a mobile device like an iphone. When you try and select the select in the dropdown it just goes away. We are using bootstrap if that helps.

[image]

Here is a link to the site http://www.lexmundi.com

Here is a fiddle where i have tried using event.stopPropagation(); but does not work on mobile and goes away when you try and click on the selects.

http://jsfiddle.net/80oLdtbf/86/

```
    $('ul.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(event){   
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Can anyone help? Please :)

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: I will try and extract the code some to make an example but think the issue has to do with the e.stopPropagation(); and the onclick on a select element  in a dropdown in bootstraps default behavior. ugh :(

Comment: I would check your CSS for an issue with a z-index rule against your **dropdown** before anything.

Comment: yeah thats what i thought and i set z-index to 999999 for selects etc. but no luck.

Comment: I setup a fiddle to test on a mobile phone with. I tried setting up event.stopPropagation(); on click but still does not work on mobile. http://jsfiddle.net/80oLdtbf/86/

Comment: Like I said, as far as I can tell this is simply an issue with the z-index you've applied to the `dropdown-menu` class. See it working in the following image. [Working Dropdown](http://imgur.com/a/QBCQs) with the **z-index** rule removed.

Comment: So you think removing the z-index on it will fix it on a mobile phone? Currently if you test on a phone it will not let you use the select but on a desktop works fine.

Comment: Tried removing and adjusting z-index and still does not work on an actual iphone. The dropdown just hides when you click on the select in it.

Comment: The dropdowns did not work in any browser **(mobile or otherwise)** for me until I removed the z-index rule...here's an updated screenshot on an [iPhone](http://imgur.com/a/QBCQs). Not much else I can suggest other then clearing your browser cache to see if that helps.

Comment: I owe you an apology and a huge THANK YOU! i hard reset my phone after removing that z-index:1 and it worked. You are awesome and totally rock my friend! Pure genius! I owe you big time! :)

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked.